# Stopped & Started AWS EC2 instance from Console, now my app won't load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Through the console, I stopped and restarted an instance after making some very minor changes to the code. However when I went back to the domain and refreshed the page, I received the following error: 'This site can’t be reached'

Does anyone know what I have done wrong or can do to get it back working?

Comment: you restarted the instance but did you restart your app/web-server ? usually it won't come up by itself unless it was configured to do so

Comment: If there is no elastic IP address associated with the instance, stopping the instance and starting it again will assign a new auto IP address to it (rebooting does not do so). If that's the case, check the current IP address of the instance and the corresponding DNS entry for the domain.

Comment: Having done this once myself, I have to ask - was this on an instance with "instance store" or "ephemeral" storage?  I learned that that disk does not live after an instance stop, only a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

- I would validate the `public DNS name` to see if it got changed
- You might also want to check the firewall settings